# How to use queue() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following jQuery code that submits a form (via an AJAX function):

```
$("#btnUpdate").on( "click",function(event){
    //disable default click operation
    event.preventDefault();
    update_conference_settings();
    $('.welcome-lightbox-close').click();
  });
```

`update_conference_settings()` is the function that submits an ajax form and returns a confirmation. `.welcome-lightbox-close` closes the modal that the form sits in.

At the moment, `.welcome-lightbox-close` appears to close immediately, without `update_conference_settings` returning a confirmation (although the form does submit). How can I add a queue to this?

http://api.jquery.com/queue/ would appear to be the right function, but I'm not sure how the syntax would work on `update_conference_settings();` code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your `update_conference_settings()` function return the return value of `$.ajax()`. And then update your code as

```
$("#btnUpdate").on( "click",function(event){
    //disable default click operation
    event.preventDefault();
    update_conference_settings().then(function() {
            $('.welcome-lightbox-close').click();
        });
});
```

Here we are using the deferred object returned by $.ajax().